# Where do I get the AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch?

Tags: kernel, security, apparmor

I just compiled the 2.6.39-rc1 kernel and AppArmor complains about a missing `/sys` interface (plus, it slows down the boot). Where do I get the AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch AppArmor asks for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. You can find the patches for various kernel versions in the *kernel-patches* directory in the sources of the package *apparmor*:

   ```
    apt-get source apparmor
   ```
2. You can grab the patches [directly from the web](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/precise/apparmor/precise/files/head:/kernel-patches/) (replace *precise* with whatever version you are running).

Comment: The kernel.org link is still down as of now. Ubuntu hosts the patches at http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/oneiric/apparmor/oneiric/files/head:/kernel-patches/